# Why this clause is dependent?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, colons, dependent-clause, independent-clauses

While preparing for my SAT, I encountered the following sentence:
**"According to a survey analysis, veterans returning to the University of Illinois had 6 one “predominating request”: an efficient course of study to prepare for a job."**

There is the colon between two parts of the sentence, as you can see. It seemed for me that there should be semi-colon, because I thought the second part of the sentence ("an efficient...") is independent. However, correct answer is putting colon, and explanation says that the second part of the sentence is dependent. So I did not understand why.

If we read that clause ("an efficient course of study to prepare for a job."), it looks fine on its own, isn't it ?

Nevertheless, I can't go against Khan Academy, so can someone explain me why the second part of the sentence is dependent ?

Comment: It’s a noun phrase on its own, not a complete sentence.

Comment: The colon is correct. What follows it expands the meaning of what precedes it. A dash would also have been acceptable. However "an efficient course of study to prepare for a job" is not a clause but a noun phrase, so it has no relevance to its status of being dependent or independent..

Comment: Does the quote really say "had 6 one"? That seems like it would be a typo if so.